# One user, multiple desktops tigerVNC

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, vnc, centos-6

I was wondering if there was a way to "share" a user through tigervnc such that if both are logged in, both see their own desktops.

I need something similar to `screen` in ssh.

I've tried connecting over SSH -X -C with the a faster encryption method but the connection is still too slow. Over VNC it works fast enough however.

Operating System : Cent OS 6.xx

Open to other VNC

Comment: Are you open to trying other vnc?

Comment: Absolutely, as long as it works on cent os 6.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is **Virtual Mode**

RealVNC is one that supports this mode

### [Virtual Mode](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.3/modes/)

> VNC Server creates and remotes a virtual desktop. Connected VNC Viewer
>   users therefore do not see what a person sitting in front of the
>   computer would see.
>
> Instead, they gain access to a persistent private workspace. The
>   virtual desktop is not destroyed until VNC Server is explicitly
>   stopped. The login screen cannot be remoted.

Comment: Is there a free vnc server that does this?

Comment: I am not sure but you got the idea now you can search based on that or you can ask for recommendation on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ site